# How to start a program and exit immediately using apache commons-exec?

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

By using Apache Commons-Exec I can start a program successfully, however the starter program suspended after the program started.

May I ask how to start a program and exit immediately so it will not block the following execution?

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.execute( "cmd /c start C:\\Users\\xx\\program.exe");
```

I'm on Win7 64bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html), `execute(CommandLine)` starts synchronous execution. That is, it blocks the calling thread. You probably want asynchronous execution, so use `execute(CommandLine command, ExecuteResultHandler handler)`. For example,

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.execute(new CommadLine("cmd /c start C:\\Users\\xx\\program.exe"),
                 new DefaultExecuteResultHandler());
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to use a [DefaultExecuteResultHandler](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecuteResultHandler.html).

See the [tutorial](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html) (bottom of) for more info.

Comment: well i modified the tutorial from apache with setting up a watchdog for say 3 secs. the program will execute another java application which is a thread that will stop running after say 10 sec. the problem is, the parent won't close until the sub-process closes in 10 secs. the watch dog doesn't work. the parent program is asynchronous.any further help,.? thanks.

Comment: I see the same behavior on Linux when trying to run `*.sh` file (the first line is `#!/bin/sh`). Watchdog just doesn't stop this process after timeout! :(